# convert historical dates in UTC to local in a sql view

Tags: sql, datetime

My data from the last years are stored with dates and times in UTC format. I need make a report where the datas are shown in local time.

As we are using summer and wintertime, thus the difference between UTC and local (Danish) time is either one or two hours.

I have tried multiple variation of code below but it seems to me, that the result is constantly 2 hours, as we today are having summertime.

```
DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE())
```

It seems to me, that the result is constantly 2 hours, as we today are having summertime.

I can use something like:

```
case 
when events.EVENT_TIME_UTC >='2015-10-25 03:00:00.000' then EVENT_TIME_UTC + @winterdifference

when events.EVENT_TIME_UTC >='2015-03-29 02:00:00.000' then EVENT_TIME_UTC + @summerdifference

...
```

But I don't this is the optimal solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could You add an information about database? A tag would be enough.

Comment: What sort of information do you need, Ralf ?

Comment: Yes, this is not optimal solution since you are including year in dates